# How to access @Html.TextBox value within the html

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

Is it possible to access `@Html.TextBox` value within the html

I have tried this approach

```
  @Html.TextBox("txtAmount")

  <script>
    var amount= document.getElementById("txtAmount").value;
    document.getElementById("my_amount").value = amount;
  </script>
```

Then reading the value within html

```
    <p id="my_amount"></p>
```

So far this has not worked. Any ideas?

Comment: a `<p>` does not have a `value` - use `.innerHTML`

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with MVC myself, but I've looked at the docs to figure things out. I think it calls that string argument the "name." So perhaps it's not actually setting the `id` property, but the `name` property?

What HTML is actually rendered in the browser?

Comment: What is the extension of your view? Is it *.html or *.cshtml?

Comment: @Whothehellisthat, it generates `<input type="text" id="txtAmount" name="txtAmount" />` (the `id` is correct)

Comment: And the JavaScript is left untouched? I know .NET can do strange things...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try This

```
document.getElementById("my_amount").innerHTML = amount;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  @Html.TextBox("txtAmount")

  <script>
    var amount= document.getElementById("txtAmount").value;
    document.getElementById("my_amount").innerHTML= amount;
  </script>
```

you could also store values directly to JavaScript if needed

```
  var amount= @model.YourValue ;
```